# Allow user to pull in `www-data` owned folder

Tags: permissions, web-server, git, github-actions

I have a github workflow, that runs whenever a branch is merged to main:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to Production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: SSH into server and deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd /var/www/html
            git reset --hard
            git fetch --all
            git pull

            if [ -n "$(git diff --name-only ${{ github.sha }} HEAD -- .docker docker-compose.yml)" ]; then
              docker-compose down
              docker-compose build
              docker-compose up -d
            fi

            docker exec ${{ secrets.CONTAINER_NAME }} composer install --no-dev
            docker exec ${{ secrets.CONTAINER_NAME }} php artisan migrate --force
```

The SSH_USERMANE is `github_user`. I keep getting this error when the run happens on the server:

`err: bash: line 1: cd: /var/www/html: Permission denied`

My permissions on that folder is `750`, and the owner is `www-data:www-data`

I have added `github_user` to the `www-data` group, but I'm not sure what else I should do to have it be able to do all the steps I've listed.

What am I missing?

Comment: The error output contains `/var/www/html` but the script uses `/var/www/mychamps`.

Comment: Fixed it. I changed the path to try something, but never updated the job here. it's all matching this side.

Comment: run `id`, `getenforce` and `namei -l /var/www/html` (or `ls -l` for each parent directory) before the first `cd` command.

Answer (score 0):

> I have added github_user to the www-data group

If you are still getting Permission denied when runnin `cd /var/www/html` then there is something strange going on - possible SELinux combined with a restricted user account for github_user. If SELinux is running here, check the audit logs.

It's more likely that you are still getting Permission denied - but when you start trying to write files with git - this account has not permissions to write to the tree. Try `chmod -R 0770`.

However:

1. It is **VERY** bad practice to make your web content editable by the webserver user unless this a hard requirement of the software you are using (e.g. Wordpress). But even in such a case, write permissions should be selectively granted. A much better solution would be to `chown -R github_user:www-data /var/www/html ; chmod -r 0750 /var/www/html`
2. It is bad practice to make your production server a git node.

Comment: Apologies for replying so late. What would you suggest re: 2. I'm not a devops engineer, so not sure the best practices. Would something like `rsync` from github actions be a better solution?